# When Does getResourceAsStream Actually Load the Resource?

Tags: java, file-management

The method `getResourceAsStream` in `Class` and `ClassLoader` return an `InputStream`. Does this `InputStream` actually load everything upon the call to `getResourceAsStream` or does it simply point to some system that loads the resource when parts of it are requested?

Comment: It's a stream of data. It will be loaded as needed, though it will very likely be loaded in blocks. That's called buffering. The entire resource is not pre-loaded *(unless smaller than buffer size)*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When does `getResourceAsStream` actually load the resource?

The method just opens a stream for reading the resource.  It doesn't "load" it".

The actual behavior of the stream will be implementation (e.g. classloader) specific, but there is nothing in the  generic `ClassLoader` API documentation to suggest<sup>1</sup> that a classloader *should* preread the resource into memory.

- If you *want* a classloader to do that, you can write a custom
  classloader.
- If you want to be sure that a specific classloader *does not* do that
  ... read the source code.  Then *if necessary* use a different classloader that doesn't behave that way, or implement your own<sup>2</sup>.

---

<sup>1 - Not even the method or class name, IMO.  A "classloader" loads classes, and I read the word "load" as having a specific technical meaning that is not applicable to other things.</sup>

<sup>2 - There might be obscure cases where that is impossible.  For example, a classloader that reads from a device that requires the data to be read in a single I/O operation.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

It's an `InputStream`. It is read when *you* read it. No mystery.